# Features for my shiny code (separate panel filters and insert popify for radioButtons options)

Tags: r, shiny

Friends I have two questions and I would like your help: First, I would like to separate my two filters and the sliderInput on the panel. They are all together. I would like to leave them separated by some horizontal line or by a specific tag that makes this separation. The second is that I am using popify to describe the filters used. In this case, I am used radioButtons. However, I would like to do it separately for the filter options. For example, for filter 1, I would like to insert popify for the "All properties" and "exclude properties" options as well. So, separate three popify for the same filter, is this possible ?? The executable code is below.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(


      popify(  
      radioButtons("filter1", h3("Select properties"),
                     choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                    "Exclude properties" = 2),
                     selected = 1),
      title= "Select Proprierties",
      content = paste0("Filter 1 refers to.....")),


      popify(  
        radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                     choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                    "Exclude farms" = 2),
                     selected = 1),
        title= "Select farms",
        content = paste0("Filter 2 refers to.....")),

      popify(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 20,
                    value = 30),
        title = "Number of bins",
        content = paste0("Number of bins refers to.....")),


      ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. It uses JavaScript to assign an id to each radio button. Then `addPopover` can be used.

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dist input[type=radio]~span').each(function(i, $el){
    $(this).attr('id', 'dist' + i);
  });
});
"

library(shiny)
library(shinyBS) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
               c("Normal" = "norm",
                 "Uniform" = "unif",
                 "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                 "Exponential" = "exp")),
  plotOutput("distPlot"),
  popify(span(), title = "") # an empty shinyBS component, in order to use addPopover
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    hist(dist(500))
  })
  
  addPopover(
    session, 
    id = "dist0", 
    title = "Normal distribution",
    content = "It is also called the Gaussian distribution",
    placement = "right"
  )
  
  addPopover(
    session, 
    id = "dist1", 
    title = "Uniform distribution",
    content = "All outcomes are equally probable",
    placement = "right"
  )
  
  addPopover(
    session, 
    id = "dist2", 
    title = "Log-normal distribution",
    content = "The exponential of the normal distribution",
    placement = "right"
  )
  
  addPopover(
    session, 
    id = "dist3", 
    title = "Exponential distribution",
    content = "It is memoryless",
    placement = "right"
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You have to change the JS code according to the `inputId` of your radio buttons group, and to set the prefix of the generated ids to the one you want:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#YOUR_inputId_GOES_HERE input[type=radio]~span').each(function(i, $el){
    $(this).attr('id', 'THE_PREFIX_YOU_WANT' + i);
  });
});
"
```

This generated the ids `THE_PREFIX_YOU_WANT0`, `THE_PREFIX_YOU_WANT1`, etc. To be used in `addPopover`:

```
addPopover(session, id = "THE_PREFIX_YOU_WANT0", ......)
```

[image]